# inDesign: how to exclude bleed area altogether when exporting to PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, bleed

When exporting to PDF, I wish to eliminate entirely the bleed area. Is it possible to do so in inDesign?

Comment: ...set the bleed area to 0 in the pdf `Export` dialog and/or the `Document Setup`?

Comment: Sure but in this case, the PDF will include actually the bleed area, only this area will not be defined as such. I want to eliminate this area altogether no matter how it's defined.

Comment: Please specify that in your question, then. And... seriously? I have been making `pdf`s for years and I am unaware of the fact that the bleed is included even if you ask the export not to. Seems counterintuitive, esp. on a 'smallest file size' setting.

Comment: or you could change your Indesign document settings to 0 bleed, then do your export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your bleed settings to zero and make sure you have all printers marks turned off. The easiest way to do this is to choose the [High Quality Print] Preset in the PDF dialog box as a starting point. For most outputs that are not going to be commercially printed this preset should suffice anyway.